# PIC18F4550 and VUSB

Tags: pic

Hi everyone I'm trying to use a PIC18F4550 with RS232 protocol, there's that Vusb pin, what I have to do with that pin if I don't use it, I have to connect it to ground ? I have to put a cap between Vusb and ground or what ? Can I left it floating.

Answer (score 3):

Read the [**datasheet**](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39632e.pdf). On Page 15 it says: "... VUSB ... internal voltage regulator OUTPUT". In no case you should connect it to ground. Usually, to ensure stability of internal LDO outputs (to prevent unwanted oscillations), certain capacitor should be connected between this pin and ground. The [**application note**](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51526C.pdf) recommends using a 0.47 uF cap even if you are not using USB transceiver.

Comment: Yes I know that in fact I have one of those caps, but for me is not that obvious. The fact is I have troubles with the PIC it doesn´t run the program I put in it, but when I touch the osc, in the bottom it works but just for a moment jaja

Comment: @Magnus512, that's why you better ask an advice on your real problem, not that you guessed. Stability, start-up, and reliability of clock oscillators is an entirely different topic.